# MYSQL CASE statement issue on php back end query

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, case

I have the following code which works correctly...

```
$serviceInput = $_POST['serviceSelection'];
    $words = explode(' ', $serviceInput); 
    $serviceQuery = "(SELECT service FROM services WHERE";
    $sql_1 = '';
    foreach($words as $word) {
        $sql_1 .= " AND service LIKE '%{$word}%'"; 
    }
    $sql_1 = substr($sql_1, 4); 
    $sql_1 .= " ORDER BY service ASC LIMIT 15) ";
    $sql_2 = " UNION "; 
    $sql_3 = '';
    $sql_3 = "(SELECT service FROM services WHERE";
    $sql_4 = '';
    foreach($words as $word) {
        $sql_4 .= " AND service_sub_keywords LIKE '%{$word}%'"; 
    }
    $sql_4 = substr($sql_4, 4); 
    $sql_4 .= " ORDER BY service ASC LIMIT 10) ";

    $serviceQuery = $serviceQuery.$sql_1.$sql_2.$sql_3.$sql_4; //STRING EVERYTHING TOGETHER
    $serviceQuery = $db->prepare($serviceQuery);
    $serviceQuery->execute();
```

but when I alter
$sql_1 .= " ORDER BY service ASC LIMIT 15) ";
to a CASE statement for improved result gathering as so...

```
$serviceQuery = "(SELECT service FROM services WHERE";
    $sql_1 = '';
    foreach($words as $word) {
        $sql_1 .= " AND service LIKE '%{$word}%'"; 
    }
    $sql_1 = substr($sql_1, 4); 
    $sql_1 .= " ORDER BY
                  CASE
                    WHEN service LIKE '{$word}%' THEN 1
                    WHEN service LIKE '%{$word}' THEN 3
                    ELSE 2
                  END, service ASC) ";
```

...the CASE statement doesn't execute...is this a syntax issue?

Comment: What do you mean by _"doesn't execute"_?

Comment: MySQL's `ORDER BY` supports column positions which is probably what something like `ORDER BY 1` or `ORDER BY 3` is trying to do

Comment: It just bypassses that part…the query just executed in the same manner as the part above

Comment: Your code is correct, you can check the sql executed, or check the error log, or check the `$word`, maybe something like `'` in it.

Comment: _"is this a syntax issue?"_ - I think probably more of a logic issue, actually? You add to your WHERE clause in a loop, so presumably there will be multiple words to check for - but then your ORDER BY clause only adds ordering based on the _last_ word? I am guessing this is giving you results that are _technically_ correct - but perhaps not what you _wanted_.